# How to export synfusion chart in pdf in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

I have a page on which i have rendered three charts Line chart,column chart,bar chat. All charts are rendered using sync-fusion chart control.

Now I have to download all the charts in pdf or in Jpeg.

Please help.

Comment: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

Answer (score 3):

Currently, individual charts can be downloaded as a pdf and you can see demo on this from below link.

Link:
http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/chart/export.aspx

For downloading multiple chart on the page to a pdf, we have logged feature request. This feature will be included in our any of our upcoming Essential studio release.

Please let me know, if you have any queries.

Regards,

Akbar